# How to I find the Azure Data Manager for Energy URI, Data partition ID, Access token Application ID of the managed identity to use a managed identity?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am looking at the following document but I am stuck on step 4;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/energy-data-services/how-to-use-managed-identity

I think I have found the; Tenant ID, Client ID but I am struggling to find the rest of the information I need e.g Client secret, Azure Data Manager for Energy URI, Data partition ID, Access token, Application ID of the managed identity.

In order to generate the Client secret I went the Microsoft Entra ID > App registration > view all applications in the directory > New Registration > filled in all info >

but I am suspicious of this client secret because when I look at the overview the "Application (client) ID" does not match the client ID I took a note of at the beginning from the Overview page of "Microsoft Entra ID".

So far I have generated a client secret using the method outlined here;
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/howto-create-service-principal-portal however I am not sure that is correct becuase the tenant IDs do not match.

to generate the Azure Data Manager for Energy URI I followed the instructions that I found here;
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/energy-data-services/quickstart-create-microsoft-energy-data-services-instance.

I also thought that the Data partition ID was the name that I gave it in the last part of step 6
of that link.

To produce the "Access token" and "Application ID of the managed identity" I am really not sure about.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Initially, I registered one Entra ID application and created one **client secret** in it like this:

[image]

In `Overview` page of application, you can find **Client ID** and **Tenant ID** values:

[image]

Now I created one Azure Data Manager for Energy instance by passing above app registration's **Application ID** like this:

[image]

After creating the instance, you can find Azure Data Manager for Energy URI in it's **Overview** page:

[image]

Now, I created one **user-assigned** managed identity and added it under the function app like this:

[image]

You can find the **Application ID** of managed identity in it's `Overview` page as client ID :

[image]

You can generate **access token** by running this curl command in Azure Cloud Shell selecting Bash:

```bash
curl --location --request POST 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=ADMappID.default' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=ADMappID' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=secret' \
--data-urlencode 'resource=ADMappID'
```

**Response:**

[image]

Using this token, you can add the **application ID** of the user-assigned managed identity to entitlement groups like this:

```bash
curl --location --request POST 'https://<Azure Data Manager for Energy URI>/api/entitlements/v2/groups/users@ <data-partition-id>.dataservices.energy/members' \
    --header 'data-partition-id: <data-partition-id>' \
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE\
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data-raw '{
                    "email": "<application ID of the managed identity>",
                    "role": "MEMBER"
                }'
```

**Response:**

[image]

```bash
curl --location --request POST 'https://<Azure Data Manager for Energy URI>/api/entitlements/v2/groups/ users.datalake.editors@ <data-partition-id>.dataservices.energy/members' \
    --header 'data-partition-id: <data-partition-id>' \
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE\
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data-raw '{
                    "email": "<application ID of the managed identity>",
                    "role": "MEMBER"
                }'
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Use managed identities for Microsoft Azure Data Manager for Energy on Azure | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/energy-data-services/how-to-use-managed-identity)